# Class MongoDate not found - Php 5.4

Tags: php, php-mongodb

I have added `mongodb.so` in both `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` as shown below

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mongodb.so
```

But still I am getting the below error `Class 'MongoDate' not found`.

Php Version - Php 5.4.45

Below is the information about mongodb extension from php cli

```
php -i | grep -i mongodb
mongodb
MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.2.5
MongoDB extension stability => stable
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

Below is the output of `phpinfo()` for php running under apache2

[image]
Can someone let me know how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mongo` is old driver, `mongodb` is new driver, and `mongo` has been superseded, see https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo

`mongodb` (new): https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

The class `MongoDate` is `mongo`'s class. In `mongodb`, you should be use `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime` to replace MongoDate, see http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php

If you want to keep use class `MongoDate`, you can use [pecl](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.nix) or [manually](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) to install old driver.

Comment: Can I fix this without changing from `MongoDate` to `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime`?

Comment: @tuk My answer have some mistake, `mongo` and `mongodb` is different version of driver, updated the answer.